# Python, subprocess, how to pass multiples variables

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using the subprocess module to run a find & grep command with two different variables. I have a syntax error but I just don't see it.

With one variable, it runs just fine:

```
path = "src"
path_f = "TC" 
subprocess.Popen('find /dir1/tag/common/dir2/dir3 /dir1/tag/common/dir2/dir3/dir4/ -iname "%s"'%path, shell=True)
```

Two variables:

```
 subprocess.Popen('find /dir1/tag/common/dir2/dir3 /dir1/tag/common/dir2/dir3/dir4/ -iname "%s"* | grep "%s"  > fileList.txt'%path, %path_f, shell=True)
```

Can someone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: might be your find this relevant http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgnP62EXUtA&feature=fvwrel

Comment: I'm at work, I can't acces youtube...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[yakxxx is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12743352/296974), but `shell=True` is not optimal.

Better do

```
sp1 = subprocess.Popen(['find', '/dir1/tag/common/dir2/dir3', '/dir1/tag/common/dir2/dir3', '/dir4/', '-iname', path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sp2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', path_f], stdin=sp1.stdout, stdout=open('fileList.txt', 'w'))
sp1.stdout.close() # for SIGPIPE from sp2 to sp1
```

as it gives you better control over what happens, expecially no shell escaping crosses your way.

For example, imagine a `path` or `path_f` value of `'My 9" collection'` etc. This will confuse the shell at both the `find` and the `grep`commands. There are ways around it, but they are harder than the above.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

Comment: What do you mean better control ?

Comment: See e.g. [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
subprocess.Popen('find /dir1/tag/common/dir2/dir3 /dir1/tag/common/dir2/dir3/dir4/ -iname "%s"* | grep "%s"  > fileList.txt'% (path, path_f), shell=True)
```

Notice brackets added around (path, path_f) and percent removed

Comment: Note that it could be more readable to do a `... -iname "%(name)s"* | grep "%(pattern)s" ..." % dict(name=path, pattern=path_f)`, that is, to name the different placeholders..